# Puma mini SSL error while connecting to rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, ssl-certificate, puma

Rails server throws a SSL error everytime I try to connect to the server.

```
[34087] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[34087] * Version 4.3.3 (ruby 2.6.5-p114), codename: Mysterious Traveller
[34087] * Min threads: 10, max threads: 10
[34087] * Environment: development
[34087] * Process workers: 1
[34087] * Phased restart available
[34087] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3001
[34087] * Listening on ssl://0.0.0.0:3000?cert=config/ssl.crt&key=config/ssl.key&verify_mode=none&no_tlsv1=false&no_tlsv1_1=false
[34087] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[34087] * Starting control server on unix:///tmp/puma-status-1596893456509-34087
[34087] - Worker 0 (pid: 34120) booted, phase: 0
2020-08-08 19:03:16 +0530: SSL error, peer: 127.0.0.1, peer cert: , #<Puma::MiniSSL::SSLError: OpenSSL error: error:14209102:SSL routines:tls_early_post_process_client_hello:unsupported protocol - 337678594>
```

The ssl certificate and key are already provided from config in rails server but even then I keep getting ssl error

Answer (score -1):

Just had to setup my app to run with SSL in local development environment. Steps I took:

1. Create certificates in the root of Your project folder:

`$ openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -keyout localhost.key -out localhost.crt`

2. Start rails server like:

`$ rails s -b 'ssl://localhost:3000?key=localhost.key&cert=localhost.crt'`

[Source](https://github.com/codica2/rails-puma-ssl)

Maybe this can help You. In Your case You could probably omit first step and simply edit `rails s` command from step 2 with correct paths to Your `localhost.key`, `localhost.crt` files.

Can also mention that in my `config/environemnts/development.rb` I have added to the end of the file:
`config.force_ssl = true`

Not sure if it`s necessary though.

Comment: I had already tried it earlier but it didn't work for me.

Comment: This is how I'm starting my puma server. It doesn't fix anything.

Comment: I had the same error when accessing `http://127.0.0.1:3000` but when acessing using https (`https://127.0.0.1:3000`) everything works well.